# Run IntelliJ configuration from command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I've configured various execution and test configurations in my Java IntelliJ project. Is it possible to execute IntelliJ on a given project and configuration from the command line?

Comment: Generally i will use ANT to run projects from command line

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

You will need to define a command line build project to run your tests from the command line, as IntelliJ (or any graphical IDE) does not provide tools to do so.

### Details for building running tests using Gradle

In the following directions I picked Gradle as command line build language, though some use Ant, or Maven as possible alternatives. The gradle syntax is based on Groovy, which is a JDK-based scripting language.

A sample configuration for a basic java project is here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Gradle/article.html

Once your Gradle project is setup, you can run 'gw test' from command line.

I highly suggest to install gradle wrapper called 'gdub' from here: https://github.com/dougborg/gdub  -- this will save typing ./gradlew all the time.

Hope this helps!